# Magento 2 : Edit id name alias

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, uicomponent, adminform, ui-form

How can I change the admin edit id name  like if I want to change xx_id to id in a Ui component form in address bar?

```
http://localhost/Magento225/admin/vendor/module/edit/xx_id/1/
```

To:

```
http://localhost/Magento225/admin/vendor/module/edit/id/1/
```

I looked in to form data source which is :

```
<argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">xx_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check your listing xml file where you gave edit page action calss

```
       <actionsColumn name="actions" class="**Vendor\ModuleName\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Listing\PageActions**">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">post_id</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </actionsColumn>
```

Go to that Vendor\ModuleName\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Listing\PageActions file and edit

```
$item[$name]["view"] = [
                "href"=>$this->getContext()->getUrl(
                    "moduename/customer/edit",[**"xx_id"=>$id**]),
                "label"=>__("Edit")
                ];
```

to

```
"moduename/customer/edit",[**"id"=>$id**]),
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two  files where a you have to changes

1. Ui listing file

`<argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">xx_id</argument>
<argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>`

2. Second open your ui listing xml file . On this file you find `actionsColumn` tag which is called a PHP class which is responsible for Edit, delete link at listing

   ```
   <actionsColumn name="actions" class="{ClassName}">
       <settings>
           <indexField>id</indexField>
           <resizeEnabled>false</resizeEnabled>
           <resizeDefaultWidth>200</resizeDefaultWidth>
       </settings>
   </actionsColumn>
   ```

You have open this Action class and edit the code.

Comment: It worked well for me. Thanks. for sharing.